# Converting GRIB to NetCDF with time dimension using netcdfAll?

Tags: gdal, netcdf, grib, grib-2

I'm trying to convert grib files to NetCDF. The grib files contains subdata sets which are time related. Using the netcdfAll Java library with the NetCDF-4 C library works fine.

```
java -Xmx1g -classpath netcdfAll-4.5.jar ucar.nc2.dataset.NetcdfDataset -in ECM_DSD_2015021700_0000 -out ECM_DSD_2015021700_0000.nc -isLargeFile -netcdf4
```

The resulting NetCDF-4 file:

```
gdalinfo ECM_DSD_2015021700_0000.nc is listing all subdata sets like
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF5:"ECM_DSD_2015021700_0000.nc"://GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W/100_metre_U_wind_component_surface
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[1x1280x2560] //GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W/100_metre_U_wind_component_surface (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF5:"ECM_DSD_2015021700_0000.nc"://GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W/100_metre_V_wind_component_surface
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[1x1280x2560] //GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W/100_metre_V_wind_component_surface (32-bit floating-point)
```

The metatada of one subset shows an empty dimension list and a missing time dimension:

```
gdalinfo HDF5:"ECM_DSD_2015021700_0000.nc"://GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9/100_metre_U_wind_component_surface
Band 1 Block=2560x25 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=-25.970 Max=30.284
  Minimum=-25.970, Maximum=30.284, Mean=0.493, StdDev=7.106
  Metadata:
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface__Netcdf4Dimid=15
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_coordinates=time
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_DIMENSION_LIST=
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_Grib1_Center=98
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_Grib1_Level_Desc=Ground or water surface
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_Grib1_Level_Type=1
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_Grib1_Parameter=246
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_Grib1_Parameter_Name=100u
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_Grib1_Subcenter=0
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_Grib1_TableVersion=228
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_Grib_Variable_Id=VAR_98-0-228-246_L1
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_long_name=100 metre U wind component @ Ground or water surface
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_missing_value=1.#QNAN
    GaussianLatLon_1280X2560-p07028S-179p9W_100_metre_U_wind_component_surface_units=m s**-1
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=30.284362792969
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.49316239946346
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-25.969543457031
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=7.1061257055032
```

So what is the trick to convert the data with the time dimension? I found some python scripts[1] and the ncks tool[2], need I switch to one of them?

After I want to convert each subdataset to a single GeoTiff but this should be more easy when the time dimension was rescued once :-)

I am working with GDAL 1.11 and netcdfAll 4.5

[1] http://pysclint.sourceforge.net/pycdf/pycdf.html and https://readchunks.wordpress.com/
[2] http://linux.die.net/man/1/ncks

Answer (score 1):

netcdfAll 4.6 is out in beta and should see a stable 4.6.1 release shortly. The 4.6 series has improved GRIB support, so that would be a good bet to try. I'd also check to see what `ncdump` from the C netcdf package says about the contents of the file, so that you can determine whether the problems is in the netcdf Java layer or GDAL.

If you think there's a bug, feel free to open an issue at http://www.github.com/unidata/thredds/issues.